# Android using JSON with list activity make force close and display errors

Tags: android, json, android-listview, error-handling, android-asynctask

I am creating Android application using JSONParser to get data from web server and using list view to display this data than  i used a **onListItemClick** method to display the selected data in a new activity with some details but the system force after I click the button to load data  and display this  in the log Cat

## logCat

```
03-11 09:35:25.185: E/AndroidRuntime(2439): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
03-11 09:35:25.185: E/AndroidRuntime(2439): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
03-11 09:35:25.185: E/AndroidRuntime(2439):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
03-11 09:35:25.185: E/AndroidRuntime(2439):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
03-11 09:35:25.185: E/AndroidRuntime(2439):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
03-11 09:35:25.185: E/AndroidRuntime(2439):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
03-11 09:35:25.185: E/AndroidRuntime(2439):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
03-11 09:35:25.185: E/AndroidRuntime(2439):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
03-11 09:35:25.185: E/AndroidRuntime(2439):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
03-11 09:35:25.185: E/AndroidRuntime(2439):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
03-11 09:35:25.185: E/AndroidRuntime(2439): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
03-11 09:35:25.185: E/AndroidRuntime(2439):     at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:197)
03-11 09:35:25.185: E/AndroidRuntime(2439):     at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:111)
03-11 09:35:25.185: E/AndroidRuntime(2439):     at android.app.Activity.<init>(Activity.java:759)
03-11 09:35:25.185: E/AndroidRuntime(2439):     at android.app.ListActivity.<init>(ListActivity.java:175)
03-11 09:35:25.185: E/AndroidRuntime(2439):     at com.devleb.jsonparsingactivitydemo.JSONParserHandler.<init>(JSONParserHandler.java:23)
03-11 09:35:25.185: E/AndroidRuntime(2439):     at com.devleb.jsonparsingactivitydemo.JsonActivityHttpClient$HTTPGetTask.doInBackground(JsonActivityHttpClient.java:44)
03-11 09:35:25.185: E/AndroidRuntime(2439):     at com.devleb.jsonparsingactivitydemo.JsonActivityHttpClient$HTTPGetTask.doInBackground(JsonActivityHttpClient.java:1)
03-11 09:35:25.185: E/AndroidRuntime(2439):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
03-11 09:35:25.185: E/AndroidRuntime(2439):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
03-11 09:35:25.185: E/AndroidRuntime(2439):     ... 4 more
```

I will appreciate if anyone can help me.

## JsonActivityHttpClient

```
package com.devleb.jsonparsingactivitydemo;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.ResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicResponseHandler;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.json.JSONTokener;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class JsonActivityHttpClient extends ListActivity {

    // ******variables for the inner class*********//
    private static List<String> result;
    private JSONObject postalCode = null;

    String SplaceName, Slng, Slat, SpostalCode;

    private static final String PLACE_NAME_TAG = "placeName";
    private static final String LONGITUDE_TAG = "lng";
    private static final String LATITUDE_TAG = "lat";

    private static final String POSTAL_CODE_TAG = "postalcode";
    private static final String POSTALCODE = "postalcodes";

    // ******variables for the inner class*********//

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        new HTTPGetTask().execute();

    }

    private class HTTPGetTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<String>> {

        private static final String USER_NAME = "devleb";

        private static final String URL = "http://api.geonames.org/postalCodeLookupJSON?postalcode=6600&country=AT&username="
                + USER_NAME;

        AndroidHttpClient mClient = AndroidHttpClient.newInstance("");

        @Override
        protected List<String> doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            HttpGet request = new HttpGet(URL);

            JSONParserHandler responseHandler = new JSONParserHandler();
            try {

                return mClient.execute(request, responseHandler);

            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<String> result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            if (null != mClient) {

                mClient.close();

                setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                        JsonActivityHttpClient.this, R.layout.list_item, result));

            }

        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            SplaceName = postalCode.get(PLACE_NAME_TAG).toString();
            Slat = postalCode.getString(LATITUDE_TAG).toString();
            Slng = postalCode.getString(LONGITUDE_TAG).toString();
            SpostalCode = postalCode.getString(POSTAL_CODE_TAG).toString();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("ASSAIGN JSON node to String", "ERROR in Assaign!!");
        }

        Intent in = new Intent(getBaseContext(), RowItem.class);
        in.putExtra(PLACE_NAME_TAG, SplaceName);
        in.putExtra(LATITUDE_TAG, Slat);
        in.putExtra(LONGITUDE_TAG, Slng);
        in.putExtra(POSTAL_CODE_TAG, SpostalCode);
        startActivity(in);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.json_activity_http_client, menu);
        return true;
    }

    // ***************INNER CLASS***********************************//
    private class JSONParserHandler implements ResponseHandler<List<String>> {

        // String SplaceName, Slng, Slat, SpostalCode;

        // public JSONObject postalCode = null;
        // public static List<String> result;

        /*
         * public static final String PLACE_NAME_TAG = "placeName"; private
         * static final String LONGITUDE_TAG = "lng"; private static final
         * String LATITUDE_TAG = "lat";
         * 
         * private static final String POSTAL_CODE_TAG = "postalcode"; private
         * static final String POSTALCODE = "postalcodes";
         */
        @Override
        public List<String> handleResponse(HttpResponse response)
                throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            result = new ArrayList<String>();
            String JSONResponse = new BasicResponseHandler()
                    .handleResponse(response);

            try {

                JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) new JSONTokener(
                        JSONResponse).nextValue();

                JSONArray PostalCodes = jsonObject.getJSONArray(POSTALCODE);

                for (int i = 0; i < PostalCodes.length(); i++) {
                    postalCode = (JSONObject) PostalCodes.get(i);

                    result.add(postalCode.get(PLACE_NAME_TAG) + "\n"
                            + LATITUDE_TAG + ":" + postalCode.get(LATITUDE_TAG)
                            + "," + LONGITUDE_TAG + ":"
                            + postalCode.get(LONGITUDE_TAG) + "\n"
                            + POSTAL_CODE_TAG + ":"
                            + postalCode.get(POSTAL_CODE_TAG)

                    );

                }
            } catch (JSONException E) {
                E.printStackTrace();
            }

            return result;
        }

    }

    // ***************INNER CLASS***********************************//

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JsonParseHandler` actually is your `Activity`. You main display.

First, you should not initialize it. It is an `Activity` and it should be started with `startActivity()` calls.

I think you should do this.

`JsonParseHandler` should be just to parse JSON. It should not extend ListActivity. And you should move that onListItemClick function to `JsonActivityHttpClient`

Comment: but if i moved the extends ListActivity and the onListItemClick to the JsonActivityHttpClient class i could not get the parsed data from the web can you help me to fix it ??

Comment: You can put JsonParseHandler class inside JsonActivityHttpClient as a inner class. This way, all your variables and data will be in only one file.

Comment: @ tasomaniac i will edit my question and change my code as you ask me to do

Comment: It is better now. One more thing, in your onItemClickListener, you don't use result array at all. You should have postalCodes array as well and you should get the right item using postalCodes.get(position) in your onItemClick function.

Answer (score 0):

From your logcat exception i can say that, you are trying to create handler from outside thread which is not allowed in android.

Comment: @ Silvans Solanki so how to fix it to make display data after i selected an item ??

Comment: How to fix this, what you need to do is, first you need to remove this list activity code from backgound asynch task. And return some data from your on post method to your activity, may be using some interface method.